# Query to fill in the missing matches

Tags: sql-server

I have the following list of dispositions from a dialler:

```
CREATE TABLE DiallerOutcomes
    ([DiallerOutcome] varchar(25))
;

INSERT INTO DiallerOutcomes
    ([DiallerOutcome])
VALUES
    ('Application (A)'),
    ('Answer Machine (A)'),
    ('Answering Machine (A)'),
    ('Call Back Interested (A)'),
    ('Call Back Unavailable (A)'),
    ('Could Not Help Debt (A)'),
    ('No Answer (A)'),
    ('Older Customer (A)'),
    ('Answer Machine (D)'),
    ('No Answer (D)')
;

+---------------------------+
|      DiallerOutcome       |
+---------------------------+
| Application (A)           |
| Answer Machine (A)        |
| Answering Machine (A)     |
| Call Back Interested (A)  |
| Call Back Unavailable (A) |
| Could Not Help Debt (A)   |
| No Answer (A)             |
| Older Customer (A)        |
| Answer Machine (D)        |
| No Answer (D)             |
+---------------------------+
```

And the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE AffiliateLeads
    ([Affiliate] varchar(10), [DiallerOutcome] varchar(24))
;

INSERT INTO AffiliateLeads
    ([Affiliate], [DiallerOutcome])
VALUES
    ('affiliate1', 'No Answer (D)'),
    ('affiliate1', 'Application (A)'),
    ('affiliate1', 'Customer Hung Up (A)'),
    ('affiliate2', 'No Answer (A)'),
    ('affiliate3', 'Application (A)'),
    ('affiliate4', 'No Answer (D)'),
    ('affiliate4', 'Could Not Help (A)'),
    ('affiliate3', 'No Answer (D)'),
    ('affiliate1', 'Customer Hung Up (A)'),
    ('affiliate3', 'No PBA (A)'),
    ('affiliate3', 'Dead Line (A)'),
    ('affiliate3', 'Answer Machine (A)'),
    ('affiliate3', 'Customer Hung Up (A)'),
    ('affiliate3', 'Answer Machine (A)'),
    ('affiliate3', 'Application (A)'),
    ('affiliate3', 'Dead Line (D)'),
    ('affiliate1', 'Application (A)'),
    ('affiliate3', 'Could Not Help (A)'),
    ('affiliate2', 'Application (A)'),
    ('affiliate2', 'Call Back Interested (A)'),
    ('affiliate2', 'Customer Hung Up (A)'),
    ('affiliate1', 'Call Back Interested (A)'),
    ('affiliate1', 'Answer Machine (A)'),
    ('affiliate1', 'No Answer (A)')
;

+------------+--------------------------+
| Affiliate  |      DiallerOutcome      |
+------------+--------------------------+
| affiliate1 | No Answer (D)            |
| affiliate1 | Application (A)          |
| affiliate1 | Customer Hung Up (A)     |
| affiliate2 | No Answer (A)            |
| affiliate3 | Application (A)          |
| affiliate4 | No Answer (D)            |
| affiliate4 | Could Not Help (A)       |
| affiliate3 | No Answer (D)            |
| affiliate1 | Customer Hung Up (A)     |
| affiliate3 | No PBA (A)               |
| affiliate3 | Dead Line (A)            |
| affiliate3 | Answer Machine (A)       |
| affiliate3 | Customer Hung Up (A)     |
| affiliate3 | Answer Machine (A)       |
| affiliate3 | Application (A)          |
| affiliate3 | Dead Line (D)            |
| affiliate1 | Application (A)          |
| affiliate3 | Could Not Help (A)       |
| affiliate2 | Application (A)          |
| affiliate2 | Call Back Interested (A) |
| affiliate2 | Customer Hung Up (A)     |
| affiliate1 | Call Back Interested (A) |
| affiliate1 | Answer Machine (A)       |
| affiliate1 | No Answer (A)            |
+------------+--------------------------+
```

I need to group up the number of dispositions per affiliate, but *still show* the outcomes that have not matched up. Expected outcome:

```
+------------+---------------------------+--------------+
| Affiliate  |          Outcome          | No. of Leads |
+------------+---------------------------+--------------+
| affiliate1 | Application (A)           |            2 |
| affiliate1 | Answer Machine (A)        |            1 |
| affiliate1 | Answering Machine (A)     |            0 |
| affiliate1 | Call Back Interested (A)  |            1 |
| affiliate1 | Call Back Unavailable (A) |            0 |
| affiliate1 | Could Not Help Debt (A)   |            0 |
| affiliate1 | No Answer (A)             |            1 |
| affiliate1 | Older Customer (A)        |            0 |
| affiliate1 | Answer Machine (D)        |            0 |
| affiliate1 | No Answer (D)             |            1 |
| affiliate2 | Application (A)           |            1 |
| affiliate2 | Answer Machine (A)        |            0 |
| affiliate2 | Answering Machine (A)     |            0 |
| affiliate2 | Call Back Interested (A)  |            1 |
| affiliate2 | Call Back Unavailable (A) |            0 |
| affiliate2 | Could Not Help Debt (A)   |            0 |
| affiliate2 | No Answer (A)             |            1 |
| affiliate2 | Older Customer (A)        |            0 |
| affiliate2 | Answer Machine (D)        |            0 |
| affiliate2 | No Answer (D)             |            0 |
| affiliate3 | Application (A)           |            2 |
| affiliate3 | Answer Machine (A)        |            2 |
| affiliate3 | Answering Machine (A)     |            0 |
| affiliate3 | Call Back Interested (A)  |            0 |
| affiliate3 | Call Back Unavailable (A) |            0 |
| affiliate3 | Could Not Help Debt (A)   |            0 |
| affiliate3 | No Answer (A)             |            0 |
| affiliate3 | Older Customer (A)        |            0 |
| affiliate3 | Answer Machine (D)        |            0 |
| affiliate3 | No Answer (D)             |            1 |
| affiliate4 | Application (A)           |            0 |
| affiliate4 | Answer Machine (A)        |            0 |
| affiliate4 | Answering Machine (A)     |            0 |
| affiliate4 | Call Back Interested (A)  |            0 |
| affiliate4 | Call Back Unavailable (A) |            0 |
| affiliate4 | Could Not Help Debt (A)   |            0 |
| affiliate4 | No Answer (A)             |            0 |
| affiliate4 | Older Customer (A)        |            0 |
| affiliate4 | Answer Machine (D)        |            0 |
| affiliate4 | No Answer (D)             |            1 |
+------------+---------------------------+--------------+
```

I always look around before looking for a solution, but nothing springs up and I've been mulling over this for a few hours now before finally throwing in the towel and asking for help. I know it's probably going to be some fancy `CROSS APPLY`. Any help appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need a cartesian product between all the Affiliates and the possible Outcomes:

```
SELECT  A.Affiliate,
        B.DiallerOutcome,
        ISNULL(COUNT(C.DiallerOutcome),0) [No. of Leads]
FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT Affiliate
        FROM dbo.AffiliateLeads) A
CROSS JOIN dbo.DiallerOutcomes B
LEFT JOIN dbo.AffiliateLeads C
    ON A.Affiliate = C.Affiliate
    AND B.DiallerOutcome = C.DiallerOutcome
GROUP BY A.Affiliate,
         B.DiallerOutcome
ORDER BY A.Affiliate,
         B.DiallerOutcome;
```

Comment: Yep that did it. Thank you very much.